# Mapping of linearly independent subsets in linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Q: True or False? Justify your answers. If $\mathbf T$ : $\mathbf V$ $\to$ $\mathbf W$ is linear, then $\mathbf T $ maps linearly independent subsets of $\mathbf V $ to linearly independent subsets of $\mathbf W $.
$$\\$$ Answer is False. What is the approach to solving this?
$$\begin {align}  \end {align}$$

Comment: To show that the statement is false, you will have to give a counterexample, that is, you will have to find a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ (for some $V$ and $W$ of your choice) and a linear independent subset of $V$ whose image is linearly dependent.

Comment: Think about the zero transformation, which maps everything to the zero vector of $W$.

Comment: Thanks guys! I finally get it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of some counter example, e.g. where $T$ reduces dimensionality:
$$
T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^2$ and the set
$$
S = \left\{
e_1, e_2, e_3
\right\}
$$
where the $e_i$ are the canonical basis vectors of $V$, which gets mapped by $T$ to
$$
S' = \left\{
e'_1, e'_2, 0
\right\}
$$
where the $e'_i$ are the canonical basis vectors of $W$.

A subset containing the null vector is not linear independent.

Comment: Thanks @mvw for your clear and concise explaination! :)